# Android NetworkInfo

Tags: android, android-intent

For unit testing purposes, I had to reflect the NetworkInfo class and stub it. I want to be able to inject this NetworkInfo object through an intent.

I've tried using

```
intent.putExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO, mNetworkInfo);
```

However when i use

```
assertEquals(mNetworkInfo, intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO));
```

The actual value value that is returned from `getParcelableExtra()` is null. I've looked at the source code for `NetworkInfo` class and it does implement `Parcelable`

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong ?